# Rendering geoJSON using D3 and Leaflet using imageOverlay

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, geojson

**Quick version:** I’m having trouble displaying a d3 element on a static image displayed by Leaflet. It works if I use d3noob’s (http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9211665) example…but I’m having trouble extending it. I’m guessing it’s because of the lang and long translation or the projection but I’m not sure what I need to change. I’m trying to display the geoJSON in the centre of the image (my code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g_at_work/qyhf0qz0/12/)

**Longer version:** 
I'm trying to extend d3noob’s example so that I can display geoJSON on static images using Leaflet and D3 (an requirement from my boss unfortunately). I was able to reproduce d3noob’s tile based example but I've had trouble with the static version.

I've been able to display the static image but I've not been able to display the blue rectangle on the image. I'm not sure what I need to do to manipulate the position of the blue rectangle described in the JSON.

I've tried playing around with setting the coordinates in the projectPoint function but no luck:

```
function projectPoint(x, y) {
var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
}
```

At this stage I’m thinking I need to describe a new projection but I’m not sure what.
Here is the code which I’m using to display the static image:

```
var map = new L.Map("map", {maxZoom:1,center: [0,0], zoom: 3,crs:L.CRS.Simple});
var southWest = map.unproject([0,882],map.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([1085,0],map.getMaxZoom());
var imageBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
L.imageOverlay('http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg',imageBounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(imageBounds);
```

It would be great if someone could suggest a strategy for maniuplating the position of the rectangle (I’m new to d3 and leaflet) 
Thanks a bunch
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some tinkering I found that creating a new projection enabled me to set the location and scale the map so I could place it where I needed it to be :

`var center = d3.geo.centroid(geoShapeInstance);
var scale = [800000];
var offset = [175, 1];
var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(scale).center(center).translate(offset);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);`

Fiddling with the 'offset' variable allowed me to set the location and playing with the 'scale' variable allowed me to resize the map (scale is a [x,x] value)

Hope this helps someone.